# How is this singly linked list destructor causing an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, linked-list, destructor, singly-linked-list

I wrote a singly linked list implementation using a struct. It is not part of an outer class that manages the operations on the list. Instead all of the operations are handled directly with the Nodes.

I understand that if the struct definition was part of a class, say ListManager, calling the destructor on a ListManager instance would just require one to iterate through the linked list managed by the class and delete each Node.

However, since this linked list is not part of an outer class and manages all of the operations itself I am a bit confused as to how to write the destructor.

Version 1 works well, its a recursive call that goes through the list and frees and memory associated with each Node.

Version 2 caused an infinite loop. I don't understand why, as this is one way that I would implement the destructor for a container class that manages the Node linked list.

Version 3 works well but is too verbose.

I ran all three versions using valgrind and python tutor to check for leaks and other issues.

Any help explaining why Version 2 does not work and why it is incorrect to implement the destructor in such a way is appreciated!

**Struct Linked List**

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std; 

struct Node
{   
    int id; 
    Node* next; 
    Node(int newId = 0, Node* newNext = NULL)
    : id(newId), next(newNext) { } 
};
```

**Destructor Version 1**

```
~Node()
{
    if (next != NULL)
        delete next; 
}
```

**Destructor Version 2**

```
~Node()
{
    Node* lead = this; 
    Node* follow = this;

    while (follow != NULL)
    {
        lead = lead->next; 
        delete follow; 
        follow = lead; 
    }
}
```

**Destructor Version 3**

```
~Node()
{
    Node* lead = this; 
    Node* follow = this;

    if (follow != NULL)
    {
        lead = lead->next; 
        delete follow; 
        follow = lead; 
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
int main()
{
    Node* head = NULL; 
    head = new Node(23, head); 
    head = new Node(54, head); 
    head = new Node(81, head);
    head = new Node(92, head); 
    delete head;     
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You should typically have a `LinkedList` class for managing that. `Node` has too little context to clear everything after itself (it can't choose whether it should clear everything or just one Node and relink the rest of the list).

Comment: Attempt 1 can be simplified to `delete next;`, deleting a null pointer is fine

Comment: Combining recursion with a loop is usually not good.

Comment: All versions are actually recursive.   Version 1 and 3 are actually equivalent - albeit Version 3 obfuscates that by assigning additional variables.   In Version 2, the `delete follow` recursively calls the destructor again, which executes a similar loop, which is also recursive ....    It therefore attempts to delete particular objects multiple times, which results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter no, version 3 is also `delete this`

Answer (score 3):

In version 2, you have written a loop that clears up the entire list in one destructor call by looping through the list and deleting every element. However, what happens is not that you have just one destructor call. Every time an element is deleted, that calls the destructor again.

So in the end, the `delete follow` translates to `delete this` (because `follow = this;`) for the first invocation. This then causes the destructor of the first node to be called again, causing the endless loop.

The following nodes would be destroyed multiple times, leading to undefined behavior, but it's not even getting there because of that infinite loop.

Comment: This was my thought as well, but then what makes case 3 work correctly when the only difference in the code is the replacement of `while` with `if`?

Comment: The **worst possible** symptom of undefined behaviour is "appearing to work correctly"

Comment: @Caleth is right. Case in point, if I try version 3 in MSVC, it crashes with a stack overflow on `delete follow;`.

Answer (score 1):

You only need each `Node` to delete (at most) *one* other `Node`, to eventually delete all the nodes. You re-assigning of local pointers does not affect the structure of the list.

Both 2 and 3 are `delete this`, which is suspicious at the best of times, plus some irrelevant ceremony, in the destructor. They are *both* undefined behaviour, deleting the same object (at least) twice.

Your first attempt is close.

Instead of confusing yourself with copying around pointer values, just use an owning pointer type, like `std::unique_ptr`.

```
struct Node
{   
    int id; 
    std::unique_ptr<Node> next; 
    Node(int id = 0, std::unique_ptr<Node> next = {})
    : id(id), next(std::move(next)) { } 
    // correct destructor is implicit
};
```